# specific printing of the rows

Tags: awk, grep

I have data that contains several rows. Some of the rows start with values 1000.0, 500.0, 300.0 and in-between to these rows there are others rows too. What I want is:

- Print the row just after the row containing 1000.0
- followed by row CONTAINING 500.0
- followed by row CONTAINING 300.0

A typical data looks like (image attached)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CNsAy.png):

```
 1000.0    -13                                                               
  969.0                  306.9  356.7  309.9
  850.0                  305.0  324.9  306.2
  700.0                  309.1  315.3  309.4
  500.0                  318.9         318.9
  400.0                  331.4         331.4
  300.0                  344.2         344.2
```

and the **desired output** is:

```
  969.0                  306.9  356.7  309.9
  500.0                  318.9         318.9
  300.0                  344.2         344.2
```

The data pattern has several lines like these.

**What I have tried is**

```
egrep -R "`grep -A1 "1000.0" file |awk '{print $1}'`|500.0|300.0" file
```

It shows the result as: **Argument list too long** Please look into it and suggest the best solution!

Answer (score 1):

You don't say how to handle duplicate occurrences of the key values or whether 500.0 and 300.0 HAVE to occur in that order so this may or may not be what you really want but it works for the posted sample input and what you've told us about so far:

```
$ cat tst.awk
f == 1             { print; f=2 }
$1 == "1000.0"     { f=1 }
f && $1 == "500.0" { print }
f && $1 == "300.0" { print; f=0 }

$ awk -f tst.awk file
  969.0                  306.9  356.7  309.9
  500.0                  318.9         318.9
  300.0                  344.2         344.2
```

To handle the new 43520 requirement in your comments (untested):

```
$1 == "43520"      { s = $0 }
f == 1             { print s ORS $0; f=2 }
$1 == "1000.0"     { f=1 }
f && $1 == "500.0" { print }
f && $1 == "300.0" { print; f=0 }
```

Comment: Indeed the values occur in order. I mean the pattern have several occurrences of these types. Also sometime 1000.0 is missing but 500.0 and 300.0 are present then we need to ignore the values and go to the next pattern where 1000.0, 500.0, 300.0 occurs together. I checked the output and it seems working as I wanted!

Comment: Yes, given those requirements it will do exactly what you want.

Comment: Like in the previous case if there is a row prior to few lines before 1000.0 which starts with 43250 and we want to contain that line also while the rest is the same as the older one then what modifications are needed in the awk script. The outcome will look like:
    Print the row containing 43520
    Print the row just after the row containing 1000.0
    followed by row CONTAINING 500.0
    followed by row CONTAINING 300.0

Comment: I added a modified script at the end of my answer. If that doesn't do it then post a new question.

Comment: Thanks for your help but unfortunately the second code is not giving the desired results!

Comment: We can't help you if you just declare "it don't work" and provide no information that would help debug the problem. Good luck!

Comment: As you told, I tried with the code and got the similar type of result but since you advised that in case of non-working, I should post a new question so I proceeded like that. Sorry for any wrong message you got from it! The last code returned values like:                   969.0                  306.9  356.7  309.9
  500.0                  318.9         318.9
  300.0                  344.2         344.2  which is similar to previous one. It didnt print the line containing 43520.

Answer (score 0):

A `grep` only solution :

```
grep -A1 "1000.0" file | grep -v "1000.0" && grep -E '500.0|300.0' file
```

Hope it helps.